# Using gerund: "applying" or "on applying"?

Tags: phrase-requests, gerunds, gerund-phrases

In a mathematical paper my co-author wrote: "On applying s to the coefficients of the polynomials defining our variety X, we obtain a new variety sX".

The anonymous referee suggested a correction: "Applying s to the coefficients ...", without *On*.

Which version is better? We want to say that *after* we apply s to X, we obtain a new variety sX.

Maybe "By applying s ..."?

Comment: ***On*** + gerund is used  for saying that an event is followed immediately by another event or that the two events happen at the same time. I'd use "applying" or "by or after applying".

Comment: I agree with Josh61. The use of 'on' suggests that you are talking about a specific instance. I would also expect 'we obtained' to follow. I imagine that you really want to talk about the general case. (?)

Comment: The 'by' version highlights the method used. The 'on' version does give an unwanted flavour of perhaps triteness, perhaps surprise. The zero-preposition version is nicely unmarked; the sequentiality is not masked.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth A very clear comment! If you make it an answer, I will be happy to accept it. (And I need the 'by' version,  I understand this now from your comment.)

Comment: This may be obvious but you state "We want to say that after we apply s..." so why not say that: "After applying s to the coefficients..."

Comment: @michael_timofeev: Right, but now I understand that really I want to say "By applying" in order to highlight the method - I obtain sX from X by applying s to X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "PREP applying s to the coefficients of the polynomials defining our
>   variety X, we obtain a new variety sX".

*(a) PREP = By*

This highlights the actual method used, emphasising this and to some degree downplaying the result.

*(b) PREP = On*

This connotes either a slight degree of mundaneness or this being one in a long line of operations, or an unfortunate hint of an unexpected result.

(c) zero PREP

This is the unmarked version. It is businesslike. The lack of a preposition does not mask the sequentiality (starting element) .>. (*transformation*) .>. (image).

Comment: Now it is even more clear than in your very clear comment! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**On applying**, as you observe is a *gerund*, and the critic wants to know what this verbal-noun phrase, in this sentence, is in apposition to. It is sort of **adverbial** with reference to *obtain*.  It works and everyone understands what you mean, but it is clumsy. (paraphrase: *When there is an application of...*)

but

**Applying** is a verbal **adjective**, a present participle in old money, and it clearly refers to ", we", which is clearly the subject of the main clause. The syntax is simpler and the referent is clear.
(paraphrase: When we apply... , we...)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to acknowledge Josh61 whose comment clarified this for me.

The use of 'on' suggests that you are talking about a specific instance. I would also expect the past tense to follow. General results (and conclusions) usually need the present tense.

**Example**

Specific: On applying the new anaesthetic, patient A immediately fell asleep.

General: Applying the new anaesthetic to patients causes them to immediately fall asleep.

I imagine that in your scenario, you want to talk about the general case.

Comment: On dangling participles and gerunds see:  http://jaffeerevises.com/dangling.htm